# Why this flag is disputed?

Tags: discussion, flags, disputed-flags

Today, I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20451636/4170582) as not an answer but I saw that the flag was marked as disputed.

I can understand that it appears as an answer (too long, well detailled, well formatted ...), but if you read the OP's question and the whole answer you will see that it's really a question and so far than being an answer, except the first two lines which are already quoted from the *accepted answer* (without even specifying that!):

> I think I found the problem and the solution (which is not 100%
>   correct). The context param should be facelets.LIBRARIES not
>   javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES....

I will quote here the relevant parts which shows that it's really a question (you can always check [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20451636/4170582) to verify the context):

> This worked for my custom tag which would not render unless I reverted
>   back to facelets.LIBRARIES in web.xml. My question is why this is
>   happening in 12/8/2013 with JSF 2.2?

And:

> Sounds exactly similar to the statement above.

And the last question's sentence:

> So I would ask is this how JSF 2.2 should work or am I (a newbie)
>   missing something; that javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES should not work
>   with custom tags?

Comment: Because the reviewers probably all saw a huge block of text and just clicked Looks OK without reading it.

Comment: that's unfortunate, normally if someone doesn't have enough time to read the answer he shouldn't make any review till being totally free. Or at least skipping the long Q/A. Anyway, thanks @animuson for your prompt reply and reaction, and for your great efforts